# How to include option in dirsync python module?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have Python version 3.7.1.

I would like to sync files with extension .835 in the source directory to the target directory. Why is this code pulling over all files?

```py
import dirsync
dirsync.sync(source,destination,'sync',verbose=True,only='.*\.835$')
```

I have also tried the --include option and pattern like this:

```py
import dirsync
pattern = r'.*\.835$'
dirsync.sync(source,destination,'sync',verbose=True,include=pattern)
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your pattern. The issue must have something to do with dirsync

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a comma after your regex:

```
import dirsync
pattern = r'.*\.835$',
dirsync.sync(source, destination, 'sync', verbose=True, include=pattern)
```

or:

```
import dirsync
dirsync.sync(source, destination, 'sync', verbose=True, include=(r'^.*\.wav$',))
```

If you are still having issues, the dirsync example scripts should point you in the right direction: https://bitbucket.org/tkhyn/dirsync/src/default/tests/regexfilters.py

I would also make sure you know what the various options do. Depending on the use case "only" may be more useful than "include"

You can find the documentation here: https://bitbucket.org/tkhyn/dirsync/src/default/

--only, -o patterns

Regex patterns to include (exclude every other)

--exclude, -e patterns

Regex patterns to exclude

--include, -i patterns

Regex patterns to include (with precedence over excludes)

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:
only=[r'.*.835$'],